# RPi 4 wrote 23GB of Log Files “urb status -32”

Tags: linux, kernel, logfiles

Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian 10 and kernel 4.19.71-rt24-v7l+

```
kern.log 12G
syslog 6.6G
sylog.1 4.5G
```

The log files are filled with `usb 1-1.2: urb status -32`. I just removed the log files yesterday and it happened again. This is the third time it's happened.

From looking at another answer, the status code relates to usb storage but this pi does not have any usb storage connected. It has an audio interface, usb dock (KVM switch), and a MIDI controller. The reason I even noticed this happens is because I could not log in as my normal user. Instead I had to run `startx` as root, which then lead me to investigating the logs.

Why is it logging so much?

I prefer not to update this pi's kernel yet if there is a simple fix.

Comment: Raspbian 10, just updated

Answer (score 3):

apparently isn't uncommon to have this issue with MIDI controllers.

From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1857085#p1857085

> cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/id* /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/product # you can compare product/vendor ids in lsusb

In that case, «It turned out it was an m-audio midi keyboard.»

And in https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?p=340162&sid=d387ddd25f432090fd1583a51cf998c9#p340162

> I've been trying several combinations between the two hubs on the C4 and several USB devices that I have at my disposal, and the result is that any USB 1.1 device connected to any of the 4 USB 3.0 ports WHILE another USB 1.1 device is connected and in use, causes the issue described above. It's not important if it's an Audio or Midi interface, it also happens with old USB 1.1 flash drivers or mouses and keyboards. Anything 1.1 hotplugged while another 1.1 device is in use on the USB 3.0 ports causes the issue.

Hope those help you. Regards!